# Remove the use of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, but what if there isn't?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

I want to ask for help.
Google Play blocked my app because:
*- Please remove the use of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission from your app.*

**But I don't use such permission!**

I submitted several times, tried to place this in the androidmanifest.xml:

```
  <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:node="remove"/>
```

But it was not accepted even then....
What could be the problem?

I used this dependecies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

targetSdkVersion: 31

Please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you look at the merged manifest in android studio, it would point to the library adding this permission.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such thing in the merged files either :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.
**The problem was that it had to be uploaded for the test editions as well!**
If anyone comes across something similar...